# nVidia GT220 vs GT210

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I went to BestBuy and bought myself a new nVidia GT220, the only problem I have with this card is that it's very noisy when it works (when I play for instance or before Windows loaded), so I looked around for fanless version of same card, and they only have GT210 and I was wondering how much really slower that card vs GT220, also that GT210 has half of memory (512mb) vs GT220 has a 1G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gainward GT220 Vs Inno3D GT210](http://www.cdrinfo.com/Sections/Reviews/Specific.aspx?ArticleId=26333)

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just get a passive cooler? You can find many types around the net. I would buy a Zalman one. VNF100 is a very nice passive cooler for example. OR you can use a VF1000 , and just adjust its cooler. As far as I know, you can manually adjust the fanspeed on that. (At least you can choose from ~4 speed. And yeah it is REALLY silent.)

Comment: this isn't the answer i'm looking for, i want to know performance wise how would these 2 card be different

Comment: Ehm.. just use Google if you want to find out the _real_ performance difference. And after what I found, you do NOT want to switch. Just look at the link: http://www.motherboards.org/reviews/hardware/1958_9.html . Use the bottom part to check some benchmarks. (Its about 2 OC cards, but you can see the performance gap between the two chip).